# R How to reassign pixel values in a list with rasterstacks in every single layer?

Tags: r, time-series, gis, raster

regarding my time series analysis I have got a very specific question for you - I hope you can help me out! I have already checked stackoverflow for various approaches, but I failed.

I have got a huge list with 12elements. Every element of that list represents a rasterstack of 16rasterlayers. Now I want to reassign the values of every single layer in this list. I do not have a clue how to do that in a for-loop or something similar, since I have to chase every single layer out of the list to reassign the values.

What I have got so far looks like as following:

```
list_monthly_stack
[[1]]
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 26, 42, 1092, 16  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.04, 0.04  (x, y)
extent      : 76.4, 78.08, 51.32, 52.36  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : CCS_1m200301, CCS_1m200401, CCS_1m200501, CCS_1m200601, CCS_1m200701, CCS_1m200801, CCS_1m200901, CCS_1m201001, CCS_1m201101, CCS_1m201201, CCS_1m201301, CCS_1m201401, CCS_1m201501, CCS_1m201601, CCS_1m201701, ... 
min values  :           26,           35,           24,           59,           37,           18,          107,           52,           20,            8,           73,           33,           47,           49,           73, ... 
max values  :          139,          193,          123,          369,          173,          198,          299,          324,          270,          175,          198,          181,          138,          236,          299, ... 
# this is how one list element looks like
```

To chase on layer of a rasterstack/list element to apply the required operations I could do the following:

```
test <- list_monthly_stack[[1]][[1]]
test[test < 0] <- 666
test[test > 0 & test < 666] <- 0
```

But since I have to do this 12*16times I would like to automatize the described process in a for-loop or something similar. Do you have any ideas how to solve that? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I respectfully disagree with your list being 'huge', you can use `lapply` and `reclassify` to get what you need.

`lapply` just iterates over the list as any for-loop would, but is wrapped in a nice and tidy function.

First, let's get a reproducible dataset:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(nrow=26,ncol=42)

set.seed(42)

list_monthly_stack <- lapply(1:12,function(i) do.call(stack,replicate(16,setValues(r,runif(ncell(r))))))
```

Now to the reclassification:

```
list_monthly_stack_rc <- lapply(list_monthly_stack, function(x) reclassify(x,c(-Inf,0,666,0,666,0),right=FALSE)
```

The second argument of `reclassify` is the 'matrix' for reclassification, with the values "from", "to", "new value".

In our case, this means all values from -Inf to 0 will be re-coded to 666, and all values between 0 and 666 will be re-coded to 0.

The argument `right=FALSE` means that the intervals will be open to the right, so as 0 won't be re-coded to 666 and 666 won't be re-coded to 0.

This is exactly what you do with the logical indexing in your question ... this means that all values already 0, will stay 0. And all values bigger than 666, will keep their original values.

Comment: @ExploreR if it solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer as solution. Thanks!

Comment: @ExploreR glad it helped!